# Google API doesn't return custom metadata when successfully create the object

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In this document it said that I can set the metadata through an normal API's header [x-goog-meta-KEY](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogmeta) but when I added the custom metadata the response doesn't return any metadata to me and I did check the object created in my bucket to see if any metadata existed but no metadata is added during the upload API "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?name=object-name"

Below here are my pictures of my postman. Do I set anything wrong ?

[Postman's header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36X8H.png)
[Postman's form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNhip.png)

I did try to add x-goog-meta-key to header but it is not returning the object's metadata nor adding the metadata to the object when I check on my bucket. What I'm expecting that the object must have the metadata when I'm using the upload API

Comment: I do not see a request that reads the object metadata. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#view) shows how to read object metadata. I recommend using the CLI `curl` instead of Postman when posting details on a problem. Screenshots are not recommended on Stack Overflow. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the clarification and noted on the warning. I want to ask CLI here you mean google console Cloud shell ?

Comment: The CLI `curl` is a command line program. Here is a [link](https://curl.se/). Amazing tool for HTTP testing that is very popular with developers and very easy to learn.